# Error on calculating and returning a function

Tags: oracle, plsql, function

I need to calculate and return the total number of different task-types involved in a given project.

Input parameter is a project identifier (ie project_no or project_code), output is the number of different task_types.

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION task_types (pno NUMBER)  
RETURN NUMBER IS
    return_var NUMBER;
BEGIN 
    SELECT  COUNT (DISTINCT t.task_type_no)
    INTO    return_var
    FROM    stage s, task t, project p
    WHERE   p.project_no = pno
    AND     p.project_no = s.project_no
    AND     s.stage_id = t.stage_id;

    RETURN  return_var;
END;
/

SELECT  project_no, task_types(project_no)
FROM    project;
```

The error:

```
Error at line 17: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" 

1. CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION task_types (pno NUMBER)  
2. RETURN NUMBER IS
3.  return_var NUMBER;
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Is it mysql or Oracle ? Syntax looks like PLSQL, but you have both tags in the question...

Comment: It's PL SQL do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why use a function when SQL does it so much better?

```
SELECT p.project_no,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_type_no)
          FROM stage s
          JOIN task t on (t.stage_id = s.stage_id)
         WHERE s.project_no = p.project_no) as diff_task_type_count
  FROM project p;
```